# android: Trying output like modifier returntype methodname parameter in android visible format

Tags: java, android

Here I am trying to take output like `modifier returntype methodname parameter` in android listview so when I execute my android project it is not able to display like above I mention. Example:

> (public final void wait(long,int))

In this format. Can anyone see what the error happen?

Can anyone tell what went wrong in my code?

```
public class DisplayM {
    public static int i = 0;
    public static boolean theEnd;
    public static String methodname;
    public static String parameter;

    public static void main() throws Exception {

        Log.i("Ramu", "I am here displayM ");
        Class o = Class.forName("android.view.ActionMode");
        Method[] methods = o.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            Class retype = method.getReturnType();
            int mod = method.getModifiers();
            Class retType = null;
            Log.i("Ramu", "parameter name " + Modifier.toString(mod) + "   
                    "+retType.getName()
                            + " " + method.getName() + "("
            );
            Class[] paratypes = method.getParameterTypes();
            String comma = "";
            for (Class paratype : paratypes) {
                Log.i(comma + paratype.getName() + retType.getName(), comma);
                comma = ",";
            }
            methodname = methods[i].getName();
            Listview.your_array_list.add(methodname);
            Log.i("Ramu", "methode name " + methods[i].getName());
            Log.i(")", comma);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've looked at the opening text you've given and I can't parse it as it is extremely unclear. What exactly are you trying to do, and what happens? It is OK that your English may be a bit unclear, but here it interferes with trying to give you an answer.

Comment: actually i'm trying to print the method in a filly classified format that means(modifier-name returntype methodname and it's parameter)

Comment: Look at the answer I've given.

Comment: sir before i display all the methods in a list view now i have to print all these in listview.your_array_list.add() how to add all these ...

Comment: Start a new question, or consult a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Class retType = null;
> ```

is a very odd assignment, and you have a `Class retype` that you also do not use but has a valid value. Please use the correct variable name of `retype`, as in:

```
Log.i("Ramu","parameter name "+ Modifier.toString(mod) + "   
"+retype.getName()
         + " " + method.getName() + "(");
```

You should use a debugger first to see where things are null or otherwise faulty, especially in more complex code.